# Azure AD B2C custom login page for signin/signup generating 404

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-active-directory

Follow one of the quick start/how-to guides I uploaded my custom html (wingtips) file to blob storage.

> https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/b2cpages/unified.html

I then tested that I was able to access the page through a web browser with success.

I then configured the tenant signin/signup policy to use the custom page and the tenant is returning a 404. (using all defaults the tenant works fine)

Any suggestions? If you need additional details just comment and I will update.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Please double check the custom page uri is same as the correct uri for the blob.

If you were using the Chrome, you can also open the developer tools when you navigate the login page for the Azure AD B2C tenant. You can see the request for the blob can copy that URL in the browser to see whether it can opened the successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response Fei Xue, however I was able to resolve the issue. I went back and double checked everything and it turns out that I must not have saved/applied the CORs policy.

I added the CORs, did a quick test, and as of right now everything seems to be working. More detailed testing to follow today.

Thank you,
Chris